# 503 Service unavailable is not handle by any IIS error pages or ASP.net Error page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm trying to go custom error when my error code is 503 but its not redirecting . for other code its working fine . But when I stop application pool I m getting 503 service unavailable error page. I want to redirect my customize error page. I tried with both ASP.NET error page as well as IIS Error page. its working for all other error code.

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="503" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="503" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="http://www.google.com" responseMode="Redirect" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="http://www.google.com" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot customize Error page this for 503 because it occurs due to APP Pool crashing [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271887/custom-error-page-for-http-error-503)

Comment: as per the answers I tried with classic asp page or html page and not with aspx still I'm not able to go on customize page

Comment: there are few work arounds yet [Click here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1946691.aspx?Throw+Response+status+503+but+yet+show+custom+error+page)