# ASP.NET Core MVC : catch 503 error and redirect to view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core MVC application, I'm trying to catch and isolate 503 error which is coming from the API project, we are intentionally stopping the app pool for the API in order to get the error and instead of this screen:

[image]

I want to redirect to a specific view, for example `/Home/Error`, is there an option to do that in the configuration of the ASP.NET Core MVC project?

Answer (score 1):

Your application running in (or being accessed through) the [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is the service that is reported to be unavailable by this error page.

The 503 is returned by IIS, not by your application. The whole reason the 503 is returned, is because your application doesn't respond to IIS, so even if you wanted to, you can't return it from your application.

See [Custom Error Page for Http Error 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271887/custom-error-page-for-http-error-503) to change the IIS 503 error page.